# numpy.where gives slow performance (2.5 hrs) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to improve the performance of a row-by-row daily water balance model in pandas. The input dataset spans 33-years on a daily timestep, so there are ~12,000 rows. I've read this into a dataframe 'd' where each day is a row and all variables are columns. Total runtime for this relatively small dataset is ~2.5 hrs.

The first day's calculations provide starting/boundary conditions for the model and are applied with basic python if/then logic to row1 (day1) using slicing. These day1 calcs runs quite fast without a problem:

```
d[:1].apply(newsoilwaterupperL, axis=1)
```

Sample day1 data fields:

```
ID  DATE    PRECIP  ET_WL   pP  kP  areaP   maxP    soilP   roWS    infilP  newsoilwatersoilwP
1   1/1/1982    0   1.872036235 0.41    0.00198425  18.01   8   12  0   0.07937 12
```

The "next days" calculations (45 in total) for remaining rows (2 thru 12,000) are set up using numpy where expressions - I need the logic capbility offered by these expressions, and I *think* the use of np.where allows the dataframe slices to be "vectorized" and thus faster. Some but not all daily variables depend on variables from the previous day, so I'm using .shift() to capture the previous day's values. Here is an example that can be copied and run - THIS IS REVISED FROM CODE POSTED EARLIER TODAY:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,12), columns=['kP',    'newsoilwatersoilwP' ,'ponddepthP' ,'soilP', \
        'roWS', 'newsoilwaterP' ,'maxP' ,'PRECIP','ET_WL' ,'infilP' ,'areaP','pP'])

def nextday(row): #real code has 45 np.where calculations like these two
    #Infiltration, Pond
    d[1:].infilP = (24*np.multiply(d['kP'],   (np.add(d['newsoilwatersoilwP'].shift(), \
        d['ponddepthP'].shift())/d['soilP'])))[1:]

    #Soil Water, Pond
    d[1:].soilwaterP = np.where(d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+ (d['maxP'].shift() \
        +d['PRECIP']-d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP'] <= 0, \
        #val
        0.0, \
        #elif
        np.where(d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+(d['maxP'].shift()+d['PRECIP'] \
        -d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP']>= d['pP']*d['soilP']*d['areaP'], \
        #val
            d['pP']*d['soilP']*d['areaP'], \
        #else
        d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+(d['maxP'].shift()+d['PRECIP'] \
        -d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP']))[1:]

#ends the series of Next Day functions
d.apply(nextday, axis=0)

print "END"
print("%f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

My speed problem and bottleneck seems to be the next days calculations (day 2 thru 12,000 x 45 calculations) using multiple np.where expressions inside of the 'nextday' function.

This is what I've tried for the next day row-by-row iteration:

1. Iterrows instead of the nextday function, but this does not gain any performance

   for index, row in d.iterrows():
2. for row in zip(d.values):

This is what I've tried to try to speed up things within the nextday loop:

1. np.where expressions in place of original if/then logic. This is definitely faster but still slow for the overall dataset.
2. numpy math functions (np.multiply, np.add) in place of the python arithmetic - this actually does help just slightly, but it can't be applied globally for all of my calculations and I get some errors. I think this is due to incompatible shape of constants, series, and dataframes in some cases.

My Questions and/or things I've read about on SO but haven't/am unclear on how to apply:

1. convert my logic expressions to just numpy instead of pandas - I think I've already done this with np.where but am unclear if there is more I can do. People talk about this being a great source of performance improvement, if you don't need the convenience of pandas. Bot sure if I can do something like .shift() in numpy?
2. cython - not sure if this will actually help due to the row-by-row nature of my computations
3. numba
4. Views versus copies - I know this should make a difference but am not sure how to tell which I'm getting using the np.where expressions

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: So it looks like `nextday` is already vectorized (i.e. operating on the whole frame at once).  Why are you calling it via `apply`?

Comment: @chrisb When I don't call nextday via apply, the calculations don't get applied for days 2-last day. I end up with a bunch of NaN values in the output. I tried it as well using for index, row in d.iterrows(), but that's about the same speed as the apply method. Is there another/different way I can apply the calculations without using apply?

Comment: Can you reduce your problem down to some copy paste-able functions/data?   Likely to to get more help.  Your `nextday` function doesn't seem to use `row` at all, which it doesn't make sense to use via `apply` (which is for row-by-row function application).

Comment: @chrisb Yes good idea - I've edited the code so that it can be copied and run. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat tough to unpack without expected output, but your your function is already vectorized.  e.g. when you have `d['ET_WL']-d['infilP']` that subtracts on *all* the rows in `d`, so there isn't any reason to call it via an apply.  In essence what you're doing is:

```
for _ in range(len(df.columns)):
    nextday(None)
```

So assuming the logic in function expresses what you actually want to do, you could just rewrite like this so it's a funcion of the data:

```
def nextday(d): #real code has 45 np.where calculations like these two
    #Infiltration, Pond
    d[1:].infilP = (24*np.multiply(d['kP'],   (np.add(d['newsoilwatersoilwP'].shift(), \
        d['ponddepthP'].shift())/d['soilP'])))[1:]

    #Soil Water, Pond
    d[1:].soilwaterP = np.where(d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+ (d['maxP'].shift() \
        +d['PRECIP']-d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP'] <= 0, \
        #val
        0.0, \
        #elif
        np.where(d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+(d['maxP'].shift()+d['PRECIP'] \
        -d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP']>= d['pP']*d['soilP']*d['areaP'], \
        #val
            d['pP']*d['soilP']*d['areaP'], \
        #else
        d['roWS']+d['newsoilwaterP'].shift()+(d['maxP'].shift()+d['PRECIP'] \
        -d['ET_WL']-d['infilP'])*d['areaP']))[1:]
    return d
```

Then you'd call it like:

```
new_d = nextday(d)
```

If your function is actually recursive (doesn't look like it is, just depends on previous values of 'newsoilwatersoilwP', 'maxP', etc?)  Then `numba` can be an easy solution - essentially write a function of the form:

```
@numba.jit
def myfunc(a,b):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i == 0:
            out[i] = #starting value logic...
        else:
            out[i] = out[i-1] # recursive logic...
    return out

myfunc(df['a'].values, df['b'].values)
```

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. When I modify the sample code as a function of the data and call it with new_d = nextday(d), sample data works. BUT with the real data all values after day 1 are NaN. So I think the function is probably recursive - I realize not for all variables but put them together and the overall calculation appears to be recursive. So I may need to explore the numba option.

Comment: I realize it's difficult to unpack this issue without real data - if you have just a moment to run the full script (5.5 sec with the 10-day subset), I've saved the before (FW_model2.py) and after (FW_model3.py) scripts with input data csv for download here: [link](https://files.apaienv.com/owncloud/public.php?service=files&t=915f51507ad5b394446664c11283ea8e)

Comment: Not sure depending on your OS, but on Windows you should be able to just download then replace the user name in 'folder' with your username, then run. ##folder = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Downloads\\NextDay\\NextDay\\'